# Dropwizard Sundial Schedueled task with Hibernate object

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard, jdbi, sundials

I have this sundial task in my dropwizard project:

```
@SimpleTrigger(repeatInterval = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class GitlabImporter extends Job {

private static BranchDAO branchDAO;

    @Override
    @ExceptionMetered
    public void doRun() throws JobInterruptException {

        branchDAO = (BranchDAO) SundialJobScheduler.getServletContext().getAttribute("BranchDAO");

        String jobId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        try {
            ...
            log.info(branches.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use my DAO in the Sceduler task, I wanted to follow the sundial documentation how to load objects but it seems not to work.
What would be the correct way to use the Hibernate project in my Sundial task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by setting the BranchDAO attribute in the YourDropwizardApplication class' run() method -

```
environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute("BranchDAO", new BranchDAO());
```